# iOS hardware volume buttons - tell press from hold

Tags: ios, iphone, hardware, volume

Ok, there're lots of questions on using iphone hardware volume buttons for own purposes (e.g. camera shutter); all I've seen are based on receiving volume change notification.

I need to distinguish volume button press from hold/release. Sure it could be implemented based off volume change notifications, like this: `On volume change event, if there's another event coming shortly - that's a hold (or quick double press); if no event is coming within e.g. half a second that's a button press.`

But. There's an app called Snapchat; they use volume button press to take a picture, and volume button hold to record a video while you hold. And that app perfectly tells press from hold - meaning press event is recognised immediately, not within half a second.

So the question is how do they do that?

Comment: @Sha I had no other way but to implement like this: "On volume change event, if there's another event coming shortly - that's a hold (or quick double press); if no event is coming within e.g. half a second that's a button press."

Comment: I understand that, how did you get it done? Can u share the snippet?